# Magento2 : Display MSRP with MAP disabled?

Tags: magento2, price, catalog-price-rules, msrp

In Magento 2, if I set 'enable MAP' to 'No' in Stores > Configuration > Sales > Sales It removes the MSRP field in Advanced Pricing from the product page.

My goal here is to display MSRP on the product page next to the actual price without the need for a popup but it seems like Magento 2 will not allow this by default.

Am I correct?

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

You need to **Enable MAP** feature in

**Store -> Configuration -> Sales -> Minimum Advertised Price**

You can also find other settings like How to show MSRP, Message etc.
Once you will add Price , it will be available on product view page.

for more details see the below link-
https://docs.magento.com/user-guide/catalog/product-price-minimum-advertised-configure.html